# Can you give an image an angled edge?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a comicbook panel effect where the edges are angled. I provided an example picture of what i am trying to get. Can this be done with css?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can be done with CSS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done in CSS using the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property.

With the `polygon()`  value you can achieve pretty much any shape you want. It is used like this :

```
clip-path: polygon(a, b, c, [...])
```

Each letter in the example above represents the coordinate of a point in the path, and each point has an X and a Y value, starting from the top-left.

For instance, this :

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
```

... means that the first point will be at 50% X and 0%, so top-center. The second point (0% 100%) will be at 0% X and 100% Y, so bottom-left. The last point (100% 100%) will be at 100% X and 100% Y, so bottom-right. This will make a triangle shape.

[Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a nice tool that will generate the `clip-path`  for you, you can drag and drop the points where you want them and simply copy the `clip-path`  it generates for you.

Keep in mind that the browser compatibility [is not very good](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for this.

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D, I edited my answer to include a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with css clipping but browser compatability may be an issue for you, see the link below for details.

https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **SVG**

```css
.element {
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  width: 40vw;
  overflow: visible;
}
.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.st1 {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
polygon {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform-origin: center;
}
polygon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 250 400;">
    <polygon class="st0" points="12.111,175.777 12.111,9.111 239.889,9.111 239.889,80.222 " />
    <polygon class="st0" points="239.889,257.444 239.889,86.889 12.111,182.444 12.111,217.444 " />
    <polygon class="st1" points="106.84,241.17 106.84,393.56 12.11,393.56 12.11,225.22 " />
    <polygon class="st1" points="239.89,263.56 239.89,393.56 118.05,393.56 118.05,243.05 " />
  </svg>
</div>
```